# Question regarding Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, inheritance

Can you please explain the difference between two codes mentioned below ?

```
function Person(){} 
Person.prototype.dance = function(){}; 

function Ninja(){} 

Ninja.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

and

```
function Person(){} 
Person.prototype.dance = function(){}; 

function Ninja(){} 


Ninja.prototype = new Person();
```

I am little confused at these lines:

```
Ninja.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

and

```
Ninja.prototype = new Person();
```

I came to know the second one supports Inheritance and the first one not, Can you explain me what is the magic in the second one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Setting `Ninja.prototype = Person.prototype;` is saying that *all Ninjas are Persons, and all Persons are Ninjas*, since it simply makes the two prototypes point to the same thing. So changing `Ninja.prototype` will change `Person.prototype` and vice versa.
2. Setting `Ninja.prototype = new Person();` is saying that *all Ninjas start off being a regular person*, but `Ninja.prototype` can be modified without changing the definition of `Person`. The key here is the `new` keyword, which creates a unique *instance* of `Person`, and is therefore free to be modified without affecting anything else.

---

### Example of `Ninja.prototype = Person.prototype`

Define `Ninja`'s prototype to be the same as Person's:

```
function Person() {}
Person.prototype.dance = function () {}; // A Person can dance

function Ninja() 
Ninja.prototype = Person.prototype; // Now a Ninja can dance too!
```

An *instance* of `Ninja` has the abilities of `Person`:

```
var ninja = new Ninja();
ninja.dance();
```

**But**, modifications to the definition of `Ninja` also affect instances of `Person`:

```
Ninja.prototype.kill = function () {}; // Oh no! Now a Person can kill too!
var bob = new Person();
bob.kill(); // Not what we wanted...
```

---

### Example of `Ninja.prototype = new Person()`

Define `Person` in the same way as before:

```
function Person(){};
Person.prototype.dance = function () {}; // A Person can dance
```

Now I'll break `Ninja.prototype = new Person()` into two steps. First, create a new `Person`, called `defaultNinja`:

```
var defaultNinja = new Person(); // Despite the name, it's just a regular Person
```

Then define all `Ninja`s to be like the default:

```
function Ninja(){};
Ninja.prototype = defaultNinja; // Really the same as Ninja.prototype = new Person();
```

This time if we change what `Ninja`s can do:

```
Ninja.prototype.kill = function () {};
// OR,
defaultNinja.kill = function () {};
```

Instances of `Person` aren't affected:

```
ninja.kill(); // Now the ninja can kill
var bob = new Person();
bob.kill(); // ERROR, because Person.prototype doesn't have kill(),
            // only defaultNinja does
```

Comment: Can you please explain me with some small code ? also I didn't get this "is like saying, "all Ninjas start off being a regular person". " Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Got it the pointer one ! Excellent!. Can you please exaplin what is the magic in this "Ninja.prototype = new Person(); " how does it makes the inheritance possible ?

Comment: @Rocky Added some loosely-explained code. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks! Great!, OT: I just went to your profile and decided to find your website or twitter link but no success! I just wanted to follow you :)